# Is there a keyboard shortcut to unhide / un-minimize (maximize, not Zoom) an application in MacOS yet?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, navigation

So, the last time this was addressed was years ago and after many, many seconds of Googling I was only able to come up with the following trick:

<kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get the app switcher and <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) to navigate to the app you want to maximize, then *without letting go of the <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> key*, press and hold the <kbd>Option (⌥)</kbd> key, *then* let go of the <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> key.

This is the best workaround I've found that doesn't require third party apps and it's very frustrating. I do most everything without touching my mouse (that didn't come out right) so it's important (to me) to find something easier.

I'm honestly shocked that Apple hasn't addressed this yet because from what I've been reading their users have been screaming for it. Any help you could give me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (hide) instead of <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. This shortcut will allow you to reopen the application with simply <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> switch to the target app > keep holding <kbd>command</kbd> > press <kbd>↓</kbd> > release all the keys. Then all the windows and hidden windows of the app are displayed, you can switch to any of them with arrow kyes, and press <kbd>return</kbd> to restore the window you selected.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!